# Start timer on button click jquery

Tags: jquery

I saw this code for implementing a timer in jquery on stackoverflow. I want to start the timer on click, how should I do it? I did that but whenever I'm clicking start, timer speed increases.
here is that timer code:

```
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
var timer = MainTimer.split(":");
var hrs = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
var min = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
var sec = parseInt(timer[2], 10);

--sec;

min = sec < 0 ? --min : min;
hrs = min < 0 ? --hrs : hrs;

if (hrs < 0) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $("#Fruits").hide();
  $("#hide").show();
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    location.reload();
  });
  $("p").append("stop");
  return;
}

sec = sec < 0 ? 59 : sec;
sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
min = min < 0 ? 59 : min;
min = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;

MainTimer = hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
$(".countdown").html("timer: " + MainTimer);
```

}, 1000);

Comment: Where's the code for button?

Comment: Put it in a method that gets called by a click event handler on some element. *And show us that logic.*